# How to communicate from multiple device to single device without internet

Tags: ios, swift, watch, multipeer-connectivity, nsnetservice

I want to send data from multiple apple watches to a single iPhone without internet connection. Bluetooth is not a good option because of limited number of devices that can join at time and low range. what can be the next option for this?

Comment: iOS does not support WIFI Direct, Misuse of Tags. Please edit your question and appropriately describe your issue, what you have tried and where the issue comes up.

Answer (score 1):

**Bonjour** is Apple's implementation of zero-configuration networking (zeroconf), a group of technologies that includes service discovery, address assignment, and hostname resolution. Bonjour locates devices such as printers, other computers, and the services that those devices offer on a local network using multicast Domain Name System (mDNS) service records.  The software comes built-in with Apple's macOS and iOS operating systems. Bonjour can also be installed onto computers running Microsoft Windows. Bonjour components may also be included within other software such as iTunes and Safari.

**Bonjour** is enables automatic discovery of devices , So the you will have a service publisher (the device that will receive information) and subscribers (the devices that will send information)

> Bonjour, also known as zero-configuration networking, enables
> automatic discovery of devices and services on a local network using
> industry standard IP protocols. Bonjour makes it easy to discover,
> publish, and resolve network services with a sophisticated,
> easy-to-use programming interface that is accessible from Cocoa, Ruby,
> Python, and other languages.

check [this](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)

also check this [project](https://github.com/ugurtemiz/ios-bonjour) it should help