# Offline communication between iPhone and Apple Watch

Tags: ios, offline, apple-watch

I am working on a project and my goal is to make a communication between multiple apple watches and single iPhone. Which means from apple watches need to send data to iPhone without internet.

Conditions

- Need to communicate with multiple devices at a time
- No internet connection available
- Watches are not paired with iPhone

So how can be this possible. I heard about Bonjour but the is idea is not clear. but Bonjour is not supported in WatchOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bonjour protocol , so that iPhone will publish service and each Apple Watch will subscribe then send data to iPhone

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62574712/2991942) answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62574712/2991942

Comment: Hi, I have seen that answer but I fount that watchOS does not support apps doing Bonjour directly.

Comment: @Anju watchOS does not support apps doing Bonjour directly, as direct connections are currently only open to media streaming use cases. It would be useful to have an enhancement request filed for this with your use case described.
So you can make iOS app and whtchOS app so watch app send data to its iOS app and the the iOS app connect to the iPhone with bonjour service

Comment: Thank you. I will check this.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me on how to file an enhancement request. Where can we file the request. unfortunately I failed to find out that.